# swift iMessage style keyboard input

Tags: swift, keyboard, ios8, textview

i am trying to implement an iMessage style keyboard input with a textview that sits at the bottom of the screen then slides up with the keyboard when you touch the textView, then is docked to the top of the keyboard.

I found [MessageComposerView](https://github.com/oseparovic/MessageComposerView) which is exactly what I want. Unfortunately I cannot get it working ( I am using swift).

below is my code:

```
import UIKit

class CommentsViewController: UIViewController, MessageComposerViewDelegate {


    var messageComposerView: MessageComposerView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()


        let defaultWidth = view.frame.size.width
        let defaultHeight = CGFloat(54.0)
        let subviewFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: view.frame.height - defaultHeight, width: defaultWidth, height: defaultHeight)
        messageComposerView = MessageComposerView(frame: subviewFrame) as MessageComposerView
        view.addSubview(messageComposerView)

    }

    func messageComposerSendMessageClickedWithMessage(message: String!) {


    }

}
```

however it does not show up. Ive printed the view and its frame is correct, its just that there is nothing there for some reason. Everything looks like it should be working. Does anyone see anything wrong with my current implementation?

Answer (score 2):

Try PHFComposeBarView Library (https://github.com/fphilipe/PHFComposeBarView), it's a exact copy of the iMessage composer bar that can be used in C & Swift from storyboard or code

Code Example : https://github.com/liveminds/SwiftPHFComposeBarTest

Storyboard Example : https://github.com/liveminds/SwiftPHFComposeBarTest/tree/storyboard-managed

[image]
To add the bar to your view:

1. drag a new UIView on your UIViewcontroller, assign "PHFComposeBarView" class to UIView
2. Add an outlet of the UIView to your Viewcontroller's class
3. add "PHFComposeBarViewDelegate" to your Viewcontroller's class
4. assign UIView Delegate in viewdidload() : self.composerBarOutlet.delegate = self
5. Set the composer bar to appear as inputAccessoryView above the keyboard:

   ```
   override var inputAccessoryView: UIView {
       composerBar.removeFromSuperview()
       return composerBar
   }
   ```
6. Style your Bar(example):

   ```
   composerBar.utilityButtonImage = UIImage(named: "fullStar")!
   composerBar.buttonTitle = "Submit"
   composerBar.maxCharCount = 200
   composerBar.maxLinesCount = 5
   composerBar.alpha = 1.0
   composerBar.buttonTintColor = AppConfig.BLUECOLOR
   composerBar.placeholder = "What do you think about this product?"
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try following this example by Andrew Bancroft [Send Text Message In-App – Using MFMessageComposeViewController with Swift](http://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2014/10/28/send-text-message-in-app-using-mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller-with-swift/).  His example provides a nice walkthrough using Swift and includes sample code on GitHub.

Just going from the code snippet included in your post, it looks like you need to import Foundation, import MessageUI, conform to the MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate protocol, and implement the messageComposeViewController protocol method.  All of this is covered in Andrew's blog post.  This should give you what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Have you find the answer yet? 
I use the same Framework however I believe you need to set up the delegate to self. IN my case it fails though I dont know why but it is written down in the readme github.